# List all RGBA values of an image with PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I need all RGBA values of an image in a list. I can use `getpixel()` function but I have to iterate for all pixels which is my aim and it does very slow. I need to do this in a few seconds.
This is my current code:

```
imgobj = Image.open('x.png')
pixels = imgobj.convert('RGBA')
lofpixels = []
w = 1920
h = 1080
for i in range(w):
    for j in range(h):
        r,g,b,a = pixels.getpixel((i,j))
        lofpixels.append(r)
        lofpixels.append(g)
        lofpixels.append(b)
        lofpixels.append(a)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imgobj.getdata()` will give you a sequence of `(red, green, blue, alpha)` tuples pretty quickly. ([Docs here](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata).)

Not sure what your use case is here, since it looks like you're just making one big flat array with all your reds, greens, blues and alphas jumbled together, but I suppose you could do something like this to get the same result:

```
imgobj = Image.open('x.png')
pixels = imgobj.convert('RGBA')
data = imgobj.getdata()
lofpixels = []
for pixel in data:
    lofpixels.extend(pixel)
```

You also could get a count of each unique pixel value with `collections.Counter` ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)), for example:

```
imgobj = Image.open('x.png')
pixels = imgobj.convert('RGBA')
data = imgobj.getdata()
counts = collections.Counter(data)
print(counts[(0, 0, 0, 255)])  # or some other value
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it raises this error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` for line of `lofpixels.extend(pixel)`

Comment: works like this `pixels = imgobj.convert('RGBA')
          data = pixels.getdata()
          lofpixels = []
          for pixel in data:
   lofpixels.extend(pixel)` it's much more fast that old one but it's still too slow for my case.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot to use `pixels` instead of `imgobj`. (When I was testing this on my own machine, I started with an RGBA image, so I didn't perform that conversion step.) Sorry to hear it still isn't fast enough.

Comment: @myersjustinc just to make clear, does every 4 integers in lofpixels represent a R, G, B, A values of 1 pixel?

Comment: @LironLavi: Assuming your color mode is RGBA (as in the example code here), then yes: Each element of the returned sequence will be a tuple representing one pixel, and that tuple will contain four elements representing that pixel's red, green, blue and alpha values, in that order. Otherwise, it depends. [You can see here](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) what other cases you might run into.